# At the lambda point, why does specific heat capacity tend to infinity?

Tags: thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, low-temperature-physics

The specific heat capacity is the energy required to raise the temperature of unity mass by 1K, if at the lambda point all the bosons occupy the lowest quantum state, shouldn’t the specific heat capacity be a finite number as it would not require infinite energy to increase the temperature of the superfluid if all the bosons are in the ground state, it would be easier to transfer energy to them?